# Do Google and Bing crawlers treat hash tags in URLs as GET parameters?

Tags: seo

Crawlers in genereal consider http://server/page and http://server/page?parameter=1 two different URLs.

How do Google and Bing crawler consider hash tag URLs, such as http://server/page#hash?

---

According to http://www.tynt.com/support/faq#technical everything after the hash tag is ignored. Are there other sources confirming this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your source is correct. Everything after the hash tag (aka URL fragment) is typically ignored. The reason being, the URL fragment is typically only used by the browser and doesn't cause additional information to be pulled from the server. So the content of the page should largely stay the same.

For instance, the hash parameter is typically used in 2 ways, either as a page anchor (think 'go to top of page') or as ways of passing information via javascript.

The exception to the rule is the AJAX crawlability implementation. In this case if you have a "hash-bang" (#!), Google and Bing (maybe) will attempt to crawl your AJAX content, which will treat your hash parameter values as separate pages.

Google => ["Making AJAX Applications Crawlable"](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html)

Search Engine Land => [Bing Now Supports Google’s Crawlable AJAX Standard?](http://searchengineland.com/bing-now-supports-googles-crawlable-ajax-standard-84149)

Comment: The Google link is really useful.

Comment: @wprl Yes, this is still the case. Although the "hash-bang" method isn't widely used, it appears to still be working. And anything after the hash (#) is still being ignored and canonicalized. However, if I were to implement anything in AJAX today, I would seriously consider using PushState (aka Javascript History API) at least for modern browsers.

Answer (score 1):

This strictly depends on the concrete crawler implementation, there is no general rule enforcing any behavior.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I have clarified the question - I'm interested in Google and Bing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is an update to this question.

See this link:
http://www.seorigami.org/google-jump-to-links/

A Hash Link may not affect your ranking but the display of results.